# Overlapping divs in a page

Tags: html, css

Hi I am buidling this mini page.

I need one div which has table to cover another div with a table when a button is clicked
.

My page before clicking link:

[image: Before]

My page currently after clicking button:
[image: Page after Link]

AS we can see, both div's table are visible.
I don't want it. I want one div to completely cover another div.

How can I do it?

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Comment: make 2 classes, one to display:block and one to display:none
then toggle class between divs on click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the use of z-index it´s okay, will make one div to be "on top" of the other, however you could use javascript to hide/show div when the other one is clicked!

something like this:

```
<div id="tab_one" onmousedown="showDivOne()"></div>
<div id="tab_two" onmousedown="showDivTwo()"></div>

<script>

function showDivOne(){

  var tabOne = document.getElementById('tab_one');
  var tabTwo = document.getElementById('tab_two');

  if(tabOne.style="none"){
     tabOne.style.display="block"
     tabTwo.style.display="none"
}

}

function showDivTwo(){

  var tabOne = document.getElementById('tab_one');
  var tabTwo = document.getElementById('tab_two');

  if(tabTwo.style="none"){
     tabTwo.style.display="block"
     tabOne.style.display="none"
}

}

</script>
```

By using something like this you`ll be hiding/showing the divs by changing their display value in css with javascript! Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For this, it looks like you'll need to make the div tables absolute, if you want one div to overlap another div.

For example:

```
divtable1{ position absolute; z-index: 1;  }
divtable2{ position: absolute; z-index:2;  }
```

In that scenario, divtable2 will overlap divtable1.  You'll need to add additional css/html to show/hide divtable2 when it's in use/not in use, or else it'll just overlap each other.